# Why is `java.util.LinkedHashMap` not equal when key and value are identical?

Tags: groovy, spock

I have a linkedHashMap with just one element and I want to compare it for equality. So I wrote the following spock test case:

```
    def "Get average value for a date key"() {
    given:
    def ex = ["08-2018": 13 as BigDecimal] as Map<String, Integer>

    when:
    def wta = new worktime_average()
    def result = wta.get_time_vals(wtime, '08-2018') as Map<String, Integer>

    then:
    result.values()[0] == ex.values()[0] // Pass!
    result.keySet() == ex.keySet() // Pass!
    result == ex // Failed!!
    }
```

It fails saying:

```
result == ex
|      |  |
|      |  [08-2018:13] (java.util.LinkedHashMap)
|      false
[08-2018:13] (java.util.LinkedHashMap)
```

I have no clue why. Any guesses?

Comment: Why do you have this `13 as BigDecimal` in line 3?

Comment: This is just one of several tries to get it go. But you can that the values evaluates to equal. (first check in then: section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Groovy, a `String` (single-quote) is not equivalent to a `GString` (double-quote) - this often pops up when they are used as Map keys. Ensure that your keys are `String`s by calling `as String` or `.toString()` before setting/using the key.

Comment: Bingo!         
    given:
    String key = '08-2018'
    def ex = ["$key": 13 as BigDecimal] as Map<String, Integer>
Btw. Do you have an idea to set this key more elegantly?

Comment: Ok - found it: [(key):13]

Comment: Am I missing something, Groovy optimizes potential GStrings that don't have any `$` in them to normal Strings. `assert ["foo": 1].keySet()[0].getClass() == String`. Where in the example code is a real GString used?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings good point - this behavior has existed for years so I keep an eye out for it. Not sure what version the OP is using but maybe something changed in later versions. It seems to have fixed the issue so there is something more going in in the example - maybe the method call does something odd.